# NSXMLParser, the setting of values and keys

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser

After the following of a tutorial I looked where the value and the corrosponding 'key' was set.

```
[aBook setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
```

My one problem with this is that this method is for dictionaries, not NSArrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setValue:forKey:` method applies to everything that supports [*Key Value Coding*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html). It lets you set a value for a property identified by a string. In this particular case, the string comes from the name of the XML element the parser has finished processing, and the value comes from the text of the corresponding element.

The KVC trick lets you use the XML parser to set values of objects without hardcoding the names of objects' properties or methods. For example, if you have a fragment of XML like this

```
<book>
    <author>Kernighan and Ritchie</author>
    <title>The C Programming Language</title>
</book>
```

and a KVC-compliant `Book` class with `NSString*` properties `author` and `title`, the parser would be able to process the XML and set values of the properties without knowing anything about the structure of your XML or the structure of your `Book` class.

Comment: That makes sense. But why would you use KVC when you can access the object properties without it?

Comment: @guitarflow If you add a new property, say, `publisher`, to your class and add new tags to your XML, you'd be able to run your old KVC-based program that did not know about the `publisher`'s existence without having to recompile.

Comment: Ok, but you would have to recompile as you have changed your `Book` class. I don't see that much of an advantage, because you of course need to know which keys your `Book` class responds to. Or else you would get an UndefinedKeyException. Hmm, let's agree on a draw, ok? ;-)

Comment: @guitarflow You would have to recompile your book, but not the parsing code that sets up book objects from XML. The parsing code can live in a different library that does not know anything in particular about books, their authors, or their publishers.

Comment: @guitarflow That is correct. Tight coupling (a fancy way of saying "part X of the system knows something about part Y of the system") can be largely ignored in small-scale and special-purpose projects. Once your program grows past certain limits, however, reducing coupling becomes important to keeping your maintenance costs within reasonable limits.